# Saving Multiple Times of Day in TextBox - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I'm having trouble figuring out how to save the time of day to a text box. The time of day is generated on a click, and I would like it to add it to the list every time I click, while keeping the older values in the list. I know how to make a list from list a list box, but I need to copy and paste the times from the box into excel. (And if I haven't asked enough already, how to format those times to be used in Excel)

To generate the time, I'm using

```
    Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Start()
    TextBox1.Text = Date.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ListBox

On button click event do

> `ListBox1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString()`

But it you have to use text box

Then use ' +=' operator

TextBox1.text += DateTime.Now.ToString()